# 3 errors. Im new to coding any ideas whats wrong?

Tags: c#

- Error 3 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.
- Error 2 ; expected
- Error 1 Invalid expression term 'else'

I dont know how I can fix this. This is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, b, c, delta, Pdelta;
            Console.Write("Podaj a: ");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Podaj b: ");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Podaj c: ");
            c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            delta = (b * b - 4 * a * c);
            Pdelta = Math.Sqrt(delta);
            //Podanie miejsc zerowych

            if(delta > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("x1={0}", (-b-Pdelta)/(2*a));
                Console.WriteLine("x2={0}", (-b+Pdelta)/(2*a));
            else if (delta == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("x0={0}", -b/(2*a));
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Brak miejsc zerowych.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            //koniec
        }
    }
```

Comment: `whats wrong?` Well, you did not spend much time formatting your post, you did not read [ask] or take the [tour], you have a terrible title.

Comment: We need to see your full code sample to help you. But a big thing that jumps out is your use of if/else. You need to wrap those clauses in curly braces to indicate they are the same clause. if(cond){...}else if(cond){...}else{...}, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your `if` statement is more than one line, you have to put brackets around the body:

```
if(delta > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("x1={0}", (-b-Pdelta)/(2*a));
    Console.WriteLine("x2={0}", (-b+Pdelta)/(2*a));
}
//...
```